# Thread.Sleep not working properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

So I have a picturebox which should switch certain photos after an amount of time.

```
for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
    if (i == 1) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.unu; Console.Beep();   }
    if (i == 2) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.doi; Console.Beep();   }
    if (i == 3) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.trei; Console.Beep();  }
    if (i == 4) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.patru; Console.Beep(); }
    if (i == 5) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.cinci; Console.Beep(); }
    if (i == 6) { pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.sase; Console.Beep();  }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Note: I've inserted the `Console.Beep` just to see if the program enters the `if`s.

I hear the beeps but the image doesn`t change, it remains the default. Why?

Comment: You are blocking the UI thread. Find out why that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a blocking call like this, your program can't reenter the UI code and update the image until after it's finished - which means it won't seem to change. Furthermore, depending on what you're using for UI (you should probably tag you question with this!) you may need to call [`picturebox1.Update()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx) or `.Refresh()` in order to force the control to redraw.

Also note that since operations can be very very fast depending on what you're doing, you'll want to insert `Thread.Sleep(...)` calls or some way to wait for user input between each image change, or you'll see a blur of images at best, and only the last image appear at worst. If you're using a framework which requires you to call `.Update()`, you'll need to do that between image swaps as well.

Comment: LOVELY! with picturebox1.Refresh works. Thank you and have a nice evening!

Comment: Glad it helped. Always note that most UIs want to be refreshed by hand, and don't forget to upvote answer which helped in some way~

Comment: I can't upvote or downvote cuz of the lack of reputation, I see your answer is getting downvoted, which is actually mean, this solution is easier for me and I don't need my program to be the most efficent, just to get it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because your application doesn't handle events until you're out of the loop. Use a Timer.

Comment: I tried using a timer but I couldn't get it work. I'm pretty new to programming. I googled hours how to use that timer but I failed.

Comment: @Berindean, show us what you “tried” and explain why you think you “couldn't get it work”.